# Java @NotNull violation message to show other constraints' details

Tags: java, hibernate

Given a `username` field which cannot be `null`, must be between 4 and 64 characters long and match the regexp `[A-Za-z0-9]+`, when the `username` field is null, the error message is simply: `must not be null`. The desired outcome is `must not be null AND length must be between 4 and 64 characters AND must match "[A-Za-z0-9]+"`.

Initial setup:

```java
@NotNull
@Length(min = 4, max = 64)
@Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z0-9]+")
String username;
```

What I also tried:

```java
@NotNull(message = """
        {jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull.message} 
        AND {org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length.message} 
        AND {jakarta.validation.constraints.Pattern.message}""")
@Length(min = 4, max = 64)
@Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z0-9]+")
String username;
```

But this latter's outcome is:

```
ConstraintViolationImpl{
  interpolatedMessage='must not be null AND length must be between {min} and {max} AND must match "{regexp}"',
  propertyPath=username, rootBeanClass=class app.User,
  messageTemplate='{jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull.message} AND {org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length.message} AND {jakarta.validation.constraints.Pattern.message}'}
```

The values for the constraints (`min`, `max`, `regexp`) are not accessed. How to render the actual values of these in the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most constraint annotations, including `@Length` and `@Pattern`, regard `null` as valid input. That's why you won't get what you want by just using these annotations.

Fortunately, it's really easy to do what you want by introducing a new constraint annotation:

```java
@Constraint(validatedBy = {}) // no validator needed, it delegates to other constraints
@NotNull
@Length(min = 4, max = 64)
@Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z0-9]+")
@ReportAsSingleViolation // to prevent separate violations for the other constraints
@Target(FIELD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidUsername {

    String message() default """
        {jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull.message} 
        AND {org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length.message} 
        AND {jakarta.validation.constraints.Pattern.message}""";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

This is annotated with your constraints, which means these are applied when this annotation is checked.

The message will still contain place holders `{min}` etc., because these are not properties of this constraint itself. You can solve that in two ways:

1. Don't use the templates but hard-code the message
2. Add these properties to your annotation as well, and tell the Bean Validation framework to use these for the other annotations:

```java
    @OverridesAttribute(constraint = Length.class)
    int min() default 4;

    @OverridesAttribute(constraint = Length.class)
    int max() default 64;

    @OverridesAttribute(constraint = Pattern.class)
    String regexp() default "[A-Za-z0-9]+";
```

Now all you need to do is replace the annotations on the `username` field with `@ValidUsername`.

Comment: Works great, also looks nice & maintainable using option #2. Thanks. To avoid any chances of confusion, I might remove the min/max values from the `@Length` annotation and only keep the override values. Unfortunately it is not an option for `@Pattern`'s regexp.

Comment: You can use ``.*`` as place holder, or perhaps even `""`. The actual value will be overwritten anyway.